# TcpClient connection receive and sent timeout

Tags: c#, .net

I am using TcpClient to connect to a socket, below is the sample code, which I connect to the socket once to retain conenction session id, then I keep on transmitting and receiving message from the socket, until I found a valid message, then I stop:

```
// client is a global object to retain connection session id
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1800);

public void Connect()
{
    message = "First message"; // first message

    do 
    {
       Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

       NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

       stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);    

       data = new Byte[256];

       String responseData = String.Empty;

       Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
       responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

    } while (message = "valid") // loop untill message is valid

    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
}
```

My question is how can I use the TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout and TcpClient.SentTimeout 20 seconds effectively in my code?

Am I doing the right thing with the TcpClient connection to retain the connection session id?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What do you mean by **connection session id**? There's no such connection ID at the level you are programming.

Comment: What I mean is the server socket will ratain a unique sesion id for each connection. I must only create a one time connection, to sent and receive multiple message, before I close the connection. Basically all transactions must be made in a single session connection.

Comment: `message = "valid"` typo or deliberate? C# assignment

Comment: message = "valid" is just an example. It will stop when the message is contain "valid". In actual enviroment I need to retrieve the string from the message received from the socket.

Comment: Actually I can use stream.DataAvailable instead of message = "valid".